# Is there a stable release build of non-Java Hamcrest matcher libraries?

Tags: hamcrest

Clearly the hamcrest Java library has a stable release, but as far as I can tell the hamcrest-php, hamcrest-python and hamcrest-as3 (and presumably others, but those are the ones I care about at the moment) do not; you can only acquire them in source code form.  This is, putting it mildly, a bit of a pain when I have to deploy a versioned copy of a library to a production machine.

Does the community around these libraries have any plan to make stable releases of them?

Answer (score 2):

The PHP Hamcrest library is available via PEAR:

```
pear channel-discover hamcrest.googlecode.com/svn/pear
pear install hamcrest/Hamcrest
```

While the latest version is 0.3.0, it's very stable, and my company has been using it with PHPUnit since the summer. Once I get some time to commit a few local additions I have been working on, I'll release a 1.0.0 version.